# reading from file and storing as integer

Tags: java

i am trying to read from a file and store the data in three integers, red, green and blue
the data in the file is set as:

```
255,0,0
0,255,0
0,0,255
0,255, 255
```

i have tried may methods of doing this but i am having no success could anyone help here is a copy of the method so far:

```
private void readColoursFromFile()  {

    int red = 128;
    int green = 128;
    int blue = 128;

    StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
    String filename = "colours.txt";
     try { 
    BufferedReader reader;

   reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
   String str;

   while (( str = reader.readLine()) != null) {

       StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");
       String rcolour = tokenizer.nextToken(); 
       String gcolour = tokenizer.nextToken(); 
       String bcolour = tokenizer.nextToken(); 
       Integer irColour = red;
       Integer igColour = green;
       Integer ibColour = blue;
       rcolour = Integer.toString(irColour);
       gcolour = Integer.toString(ibColour);
       bcolour = Integer.toString(igColour);
     contents.append(str);
       printColourRow(red, green, blue);    
       }
   {
     reader.close();
  }
   } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("error");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? You should use String.split instead of tokenizers

Comment: Where do you want to store the data?

Comment: the problem is not that i get an error message the program compiles fine but the red green and blue integers always default to 128 as declared at the start of the method i need to find a way of splitting the three numbers on each row and assigning them to red green and blue

Comment: the data will be outputted to an html file, that is already taken care of

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
   Integer irColour = red;
   Integer igColour = green;
   Integer ibColour = blue;
   rcolour = Integer.toString(irColour);
   gcolour = Integer.toString(ibColour);
   bcolour = Integer.toString(igColour);
```

with

```
   red = Integer.parseInt(rcolour); 
   green = Integer.parseInt(gcolour); 
   blue = Integer.parseInt(bcolour);
```

Comment: i tried doing this but now i have an error from the output to file method, though it it is an exeption error from my try catch block

Comment: i am not looking for the work to be done for me just pointers on where i am going wrong!

Comment: Scratch the last, i got it working thank you for the advise, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `rcolour`, `gcolour`, and `bcolour` values from this file, but you are not doing anything with them. Then you set these values to 128. Then you are printing a color row (using printColourRow) the values 128,128,128. The variables `red`, `green`, and `blue` are all set to 128 at the top and are never changed.

Shouldn't you be printing out what you are reading from the file? As in:

```
printColourRow(Integer.parseInt(rcolour),
               Integer.parseInt(gcolour),
               Integer.parseInt(bcolour));
```